# Di.xml error Cannot instantiate interface

Tags: magento2, module, di

I am trying to use the **di.xml** to pull a table from different module to populate a dropdown in the admin panel. When I write the XML code below it is throwing this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Symfony\Component                                                                                                                                                             \Console\Output\OutputInterface in /var/www/vhosts/dev.vendor.com/vendor/magento/                                                                                                                                                             framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/** Grid di xml
 * @category  Vendor
 * @package   Vendor_namespacesearch
 * @author    Vendor
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2010-2017 Vendor Software Private Limited (https://webkul.com)
 * @license   https://store.webkul.com/license.html
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\namespacesearch\Api\Data\GridInterface" type="Vendor\namespacesearch\Model\Grid" />

    <virtualType name="Vendor\namespacesearch\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">productcms_applicationsearch</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\namespacesearch\Model\ResourceModel\Grid</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="namespacesearch_record_grid_list_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\namespacesearch\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\namespacesearch\Logger\Handler">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filesystem" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Driver\File</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\namespacesearch\Logger\Logger">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customLogHandler</argument>
            <argument name="handlers"  xsi:type="array">
                <item name="system" xsi:type="object">Vendor\namespacesearch\Logger\Handler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="namespaces_record_grid_list_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\namespaces\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
    <type name="Vendor\namespaces\Model\ResourceModel\Grid\Grid\Collection">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">productcms_application</argument>
            <argument name="eventPrefix" xsi:type="string">Vendor_namespacesearch_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="eventObject" xsi:type="string">Vendor_grid_collection</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Vendor\namespaces\Model\ResourceModel\Grid</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

Thanks for the help